# Can I send access token using GET method?

Tags: rest, http, get, jwt

I'm building RESTful API, but I have some question while implementing `/valid` 
endpoint.

`/valid` endpoint checks token expiration.

1. Is GET method good choice for this endpoint?
2. Is there any problem with sending token using GET method?
   (like http://some.api/valid?access_token=ACCESS.TOKEN.STRING )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `GET`, your server log will be full of access tokens. This may be a security issue to consider.

What you're doing is essentially `RPC`, passing a parameter (access token) into a function (validate).

To do it using `REST`, you could consider the resource as the access token. As you have it, it's already been created (`POST`) so you would want to interact with it in some way. `PUT` updates a resource but you're not updating but you're not using REST either so it doesn't really matter. You could use `POST` but as I said, the resource (access token) has already been created.

So to get as close as possible to `REST`, you could:

```
PUT /accesstoken/validate
body: ACCESS.TOKEN.STRING
```

and get a suitable response. It also allows the server to track whether the access token has ever been validated, if that's of relevance. As it's RPC, it means the server could do other things that may update the resource in some way. i.e. number of times it's been validated and the ip address it was validated from, increasing security perhaps.